# Passing props into a constant function in Reactive Native

Tags: react-native

Given a *styles.js* which controls all of my theming, I'm having problems passing props into a constant function from inside the same *styles.js*, which works in the expected way with other exports.

The reason for the constant function is to instantiate something with more complexity which I've abstracted away under a "component", dropdown.js

Given the following, which works, in styles.js:

```
export const **SubText **= styled.Text`
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors['subtext_colour']};
    padding: 5px;
;
```

and can be called from elsewhere in my app (after correctly importing), such as (partial/incomplete code);
in "Create Profile.tsx", where I import "SubText" from *styles.js*

```
import { 
  HeaderText, 
  SubText, 
  HighlightText,
  Scroll
} from '../assets/styles/Styles'

  return (
    <Scroll>

      <HeaderText>Select from an existing Profile:</HeaderText>
      <**SubText**>Some stuff</**SubText**>

      <HeaderText>Create a Profile:</HeaderText>
      <**SubText**>Name:</**SubText**>
```

The problem I'm having is with abstracting a component that I've imported into my styles.js, which I'd like to pass props down to, but how, exactly...

In Styles.js:
I'm picking on `selectedItemText` because it's something text-based that I can use to quickly validate if I'm passing *something* or *not*

```
import { Dropdown } from '../components/Dropdown';

const getprimaryobjectborder_colour = String(`${(props) => props.theme.colors['primaryobjectborder_colour']}`)

export const MyDropdown = ({ selectedItemText, options, b=(props) => props.theme.colors['primaryobjectborder_colour']} ) => (
  <Dropdown
    selectedItemText={selectedItemText}
    //selectedItemText={(props) => props.theme.colors['primaryobjectborder_colour']} // doesn't work
    //selectedItemText = {b.primaryobjectborder_colour} // doesn't work
    //selectedItemText={b} // doesn't work
    //selectedItemText = {getprimaryobjectborder_colour} //doesn't work
    options = {options} 
    selectedItemBackgroundColour = {(props) => props.theme.colors['textinputbackground_colour']}
    selectedItemBorderColour = {(props) => props.theme.colors['primaryobjectborder_colour']}
  />
);
```

Where I'm using it in my code (Preferences.tsx),
This works fine, if I'm passing props.theme from where I used this component.
It's the code above I'm more interested in, where I'm trying to access props which I DID NOT pass in...

```
      <HeaderText>Theme:</HeaderText>
      <MyDropdown
        selectedItemText={props.Theme}
        options={Themedata}
      />
```

In the code above for Styles.js, all the commented lines are what I've tried to do, which is access the props theme colors, which is fine for anything defined behind back-ticks, but not here.
I'm expecting the theme color to be passed to my "component" Dropdown.js: /components/Dropdown

**Simplified**; if this:

```
    export const SText = styled.Text`
        color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors['scol']};
    `;
```

Then, Why not this:

```
  const get_scol = (props) => {
    return
    'text'// works
    //props.theme.colors['scol'] // not exist
    //props.theme.colors.scol // not exist
    //(props) => props.theme.colors['scol'] // no data
    //(props) => props.theme.colors['scol'].Text // no data
    //(props) => props.theme.colors.scol.Text // no data
    // colors.scol // not exist

    // console.log ('a', `${(props) => props.theme.colors['scol']}`.toString()) // function [bytecode
  }
```

And if so, how?